# Eigenvalues of a sum of power of a matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$A$ is defined as a real $n×n$ matrix. $B$ is defined as:
$$B=A+A^2+A^3+A^4+ \dots +A^n$$
What's the relation between eigenvalues of $A$ and eigenvalues of $B$?
Can anyone give me some materials?

Comment: Hint : if $X $ is an eigenvector of $A$ associated with the eigenvalue  $\lambda $, then  $AX=\lambda X $. What is $BX $ ?

Comment: @krirkrirk Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$ and $v$ a corresponding eigenvector. Then
$$
Bv = (A+A^2+\cdots + A^n)v\\
= Av+A^2v + \cdots +A^nv\\
= \lambda v + \lambda^2v + \cdots + \lambda^nv\\
= (\lambda + \lambda^2+\cdots + \lambda^n)v
$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

If $A$ is diagonalizable, say $A = VDV^{-1}$ then
$$
B = \sum_{k=1}^n \left(VDV^{-1}\right)^k
  = \sum_{k=1}^n VD^kV^{-1}
  = V \left(\sum_{k=1}^n D^k \right)V^{-1}
$$
and $D$ is a diagonal matrix. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Do you mean $V^{-1}$ instead of $V^T$?

Comment: @Arthur fixed thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to prove that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $\phi(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $\phi(A)$ for every $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $\phi(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]$

Answer (score 0):

I want to add a bit with gt6989b that if you consider it in complex $\operatorname{GL}(n, \Bbb C)$ then it will always be equivalent with a Jordan canonical block form.

Now for your answer for any polynomial $p(x)$; $p(A)v=P(\lambda)v$ holds if $Av=\lambda v$.